# How to get imported row id in Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) and I need to get id of imported rows during import.

## code

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $link = new Link([
      'site_name'    => $row['site_name'],
    ]);

    $name = explode('-', $row['site_name']);
    $site = Site::whereIn('name', $name)->pluck('id');
    $link->sites()->sync($site, false);  // this `$link` can't get id of imported row

    return $link;
}
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'link_id'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `link_sites` (`link_id`, `site_id`)
>   values (?, 14))

**Any idea?**

Comment: For some reason your `link_id` is null

Comment: @PavloZhukov yes it seems `$link` doesn't return data after row imported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved

I've changed my function to use `onEachRow` and it's working now.

```
public function onRow(Row $row)
{
    $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();
    $row = $row->toArray();
    
    $link = Link::create([
        'site_name'    => $row['site_name'],
    ]);

    $name = explode('-', $row['site_name']);
    $site = Site::whereIn('name', $name)->pluck('id');
    $link->sites()->sync($site, false);
}
```

[Document](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#handling-persistence-on-your-own)